# Поиск самой длинной строки в массиве

Tags: java, массивы, функции, сортировка, методы

Задание звучит так:

> You should implement the function String findLongestName(String []
> names) which takes an array of Strings as an input containing a list
> of names, and return the String that has the longest name.
>
> To do so, try to follow these steps:
>
> 1. The first step is to calculate and store the length of the input
>    array, this is done using names.length; and store that in an integer
>    variable.
> 2. Then create a new String called longestName that will store
>    the longest name in the array of names, initialize it with the first
>    name in the array, that is names[0].
> 3. Next, you should create a for
>    loop that will compare every name in the array using names[i] against
>    the longestName. Only replace the longestName value if the names[i] is
>    longer.
> 4. Finally, return the longestName variable as the return value
>    of the function.

Вот мой код:

```java
public String findLongestName(String[] names) {
    int size = names.length;
    String longestName = names[0];
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        if (names[i].length() > longestName.length()) {
            longestName = names[i];
        }
    }
    return longestName;
}
```

На попытку воспроизвести код выходит ошибка, что нужно что-то исправить *(в прямом смысле что-то, так как прохожу обучение языку на сайте)*. В чем проблема, не подскажите? Принципиально не хочу смотреть ответ и пытаюсь сам понять в чем моя ошибка.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Хм, даже не знаю, как ответить, чтобы Вам не смотреть ответ ). Тем не менее, иметь принципы в наше время - похвально.

Индексы элементов в массиве изменяются от нуля до `length` минус один.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  ...
```

Comment: И вправду получилось, код заработал! А можете, пожалуйста, поподробнее объяснить, что вы имели в виду? Я только учусь ^^"

Comment: @AkiraKubo В языке Java индексирование элементов массива начинается с нуля - у первого элемента индекс `0`. Соответственно, у последнего элемента индекс не `length`, а `length - 1`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое! :)

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска максимального элемента в массиве есть метод [`Stream.max(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"Иван", "Пётр", "Фёдор"};

    System.out.println(findLongestName(names)); // Фёдор
}

public static String findLongestName(String[] names) {
    return Arrays.stream(names).max(Comparator.comparing(String::length)).get();
}
```